# Scala recursion solving a sudoku

Tags: scala, recursion

I need to write a method that will return the contents of a particular row (index of it is inputted as method parameter). I do not have a huge experience in Scala and therefore I am getting confused. I would do something like a for loop for 1 to 9 if row is not empty return value, however, I have to use recursion and no loops and I am also given this method definitions :

```
   def r(r: Int): Set[Int] = {
  //code
   }
```

I also do not know how Set works. Any help would be really appreciated. PS: I am not asking for complete code, an algorithm explanation would be more than enough!

Comment: Why do you **have** to use recursion with a **given** method signature? Is this a school project maybe?

Comment: Googling for *sudoku algorithm* got me this as top result. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku_solving_algorithms

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question. I mean I understand that you are required to use recursion rather than loops (and that's pretty easy), but I don't understand what you are expected to do with that method signature. e.g.

- Why is it returning a set?
- What does the parameter mean?
- What else is in scope that you need to use to solve the problem?

One of the most important parts of leaning to be a programmer is learning to state problems clearly, because often, when the problem is made clear, the solution is obvious.

I wrote and published a Scala Sudoku solver that uses a lot of recursion, but it won't help you here unless you learn some basics.

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming is very different from imperative programming that most people start with when they learn programming. If this is your first functional language, I suggest taking a course like this: https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun. This uses Scala to teach functional language basics, and might help you.

Not able to use loops does not always mean you have to implement a recursive function. There are standard functional constructs like `map`, `filter`, and so on, that you can use.

PS: A sudoku solver is what I tried to make when I was starting learning Scala. Here is the code if you want to take a look: https://github.com/saileshmittal/Scadoku.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Sudoku solver using immutable data structures:

```
val n = 9
val s = Math.sqrt(n).toInt
type Board = IndexedSeq[IndexedSeq[Int]]

def solve(board: Board, cell: Int = 0): Option[Board] = (cell%n, cell/n) match {
  case (r, `n`) => Some(board)
  case (r, c) if board(r)(c) > 0 => solve(board, cell + 1)
  case (r, c) =>
    def cells(i: Int) = Seq(board(r)(i), board(i)(c), board(s*(r/s) + i/s)(s*(c/s) + i%s))

    def guess(x: Int) = solve(board.updated(r, board(r).updated(c, x)), cell + 1)  

    1 to n diff (board.indices flatMap cells) collectFirst Function.unlift(guess)
}
```

Here is a full usage: https://gist.github.com/pathikrit/a32e17832296befd6b94

Comment: What does the value at `board(s*(r/s) + i/s)(s*(c/s) + i%s)` represent?

Comment: The ith cell in the 3x3 box which contains (r, c).